# ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_4: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python

I am trying to build a resnet-50 model, but I am getting the folowing error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_4: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2. Can anyone help me.

This is my code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization

input_shape=(224,224,3)
model = Sequential()

model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False,
                   input_tensor=None,
                   input_shape= input_shape,
                   pooling='avg',
                   classes=2,
                   weights=resnet_weights_path))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.layers[0].trainable = False
model.summary()
```

Comment: You can't simply add a new Layer after the `ResNet` model initialization. That is a MODEL not a LAYER. Also, you already have the correct parameters provided to the ResNet model. Check out this [documentation](https://keras.io/api/applications/resnet/#resnet50-function)

Comment: Thanks @JacobK, I am new to deep learning, so I don't really know how to do it. Can you show me, please?

Comment: Here's a good [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-and-coding-a-resnet-in-keras-446d7ff84d33) that explains the architecture used in the `ResNet` model as well as how to implement in Keras. If you still need help, let me know!